# Строение без стен имеет какое-то название в русском языке?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Это не веранда и не терраса, поскольку стоит отдельно: крыша, фундамент, настил и "колонны".

Answer (score 3):

Например, [беседка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0). Но зависит от размера и целей постройки.

Comment: Посмотрел по картинкам в гугле: беседка подходит. (Хотя действие описываемое происходит в Самоа).

Answer (score 1):

**НАВЕ́С**, -а; м.

Кузнецов: кровля на каких-либо опорах для защиты от солнца или дождя, снега.

Ефремова: кровля на столбах или иных опорах для защиты от солнца или непогоды.

Строительный словарь: скатная крыша, опирающаяся на столбы и/или иные опоры, предназначенная для укрытия от дождя, снега или солнечных лучей.

Энциклопедия сельского хозяйства: лёгкое каркасное, чаще деревянное сооружение для защиты с.-х. животных, кормов, подстилки, с.-х. техники и др. от дождя, ветра и т. п. Может быть отдельно стоящим или пристроенным к стене здания.

[Виды навесов](http://sdelajrukami.ru/naves-svoimi-rukami/)

Answer (score 1):

Oдин из вариантов ответа - открытая ротонда.
И в некоторых случаях - открытый павильон.

Answer (score 0):

Лёгкое покрытие можно назвать тентом. Горизонтальная, на стойках, солнцезащитная (дощатая в разбежку) конструкция называется перголой.

Comment: Пергола не подходит: судя по картинкам гугла, у нее крыша не сплошная - от дождя не спасет. A "tent" - так в англоязычных странах называют туристические палатки. Но вариант учту "для общего развития".

Comment: Леса, хоть и временное, но тоже — строение: настил по каркасу. Покрытия выполняются купольными и  на основе пространственных структур. Также можно утверждать, что шалаш представляет собой строение без стен.